# selenium-IDE-2.9.0 -[error] Element css=li.xspPickerItem.xspPickerItemHover not found

Tags: selenium, xpages

I am using `selenium_IDE 2.9.0` for testing & code is of `xpages` in which namepicker control is used. 
While runnig  test case i am phasing error.

where in selenium

command=  click

target=   css=li.xspPickerItem.xspPickerItemHover

log error is:

```
 [info] Executing: |click | xpath=(//img[@alt='Open Picker'])[3] | |
    [info] Executing: |click | //div[@id='extlib_dijit_PickerName_0']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/ul/li[13] | |
    [info] Executing: |click | css=li.xspPickerItem.xspPickerItemHover | |
    [error] Element css=li.xspPickerItem.xspPickerItemHover not found
    [info] Test case failed
```

Code of namepicker control where it  might causes problem:

```
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="members">
<xe:this.dialogTitle><![CDATA[#{javascript:return application['intern_member_picker_title'];}]]></xe:this.dialogTitle>
<xe:this.dataProvider>
<xe:dominoViewNamePicker loaded="true" label="$39" labelColumn="$39">
<xe:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var nab:NotesDatabase=session.getDatabase(database.getServer(),"names.nsf");
return  database.getServer() + "!!" + nab.getFilePath();}]]></xe:this.databaseName>
<xe:this.viewName><![CDATA[#{javascript:return ("($PeopleGroupsFlat)");}]]></xe:this.viewName>
</xe:dominoViewNamePicker>
</xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

Can any one help me how to resolve.Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The class `xspPickerItemHover` is only activated on an item in the list when the mouse hovers over that item. When Selenium is running a test, that would not be the case, so that class would not be present. Thus no element can be found and an error occurs. You'll need to remove that class: `<td>css=li.xspPickerItem</td>`, but then I foresee another problem.

Every item in the picker will match the `li.xspPickerItem` selector. I presume you want to click on one item in particular. So you'll need to specify something more specific for that selector, or I think you'll have more problems. Perhaps something like this:

```
<td>//ul[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " xspPickerBody ")]/li[2]</td>
```